# Why does GCC use mov/mfence instead of xchg to implement C11's atomic_store?

Tags: c, gcc, atomic, memory-barriers

In [C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - atomic<> Weapons, 2 of 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) Herb Sutter argues (around 0:38:20) that one should use `xchg`, not `mov`/`mfence` to implement `atomic_store` on x86. He also seems to suggest that this particular instruction sequence is what everyone agreed one. However, GCC uses the latter. Why does GCC use this particular implementation?

Comment: This answer in a previous question pretty much covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22283062/3826372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, the `mov` and `mfence` method is faster as it does not trigger a redundant memory read like the `xchg` which will take time. The x86 CPU guarantees strict ordering of writes between threads anyway so so it is enough.

Note some very old CPUs have a bug in the `mov` instruction which makes `xchg` necessary but this is from a very long time ago and working around this is not worth the overhead to most users.

Credit to @amdn for the information on the bug in old Pentium CPUs causing `xchg` to be needed in the past.

Comment: I'm curious as to why Herb Sutter argues (in 2012) for using `xchg` then, since he seems knowledgable on the subject.

Comment: @tibbe My personal guess would be that `xchg` was better at some point in the past, I have found various bits of dated docs that `mfence` + `mov` was slow on some Athlons and broken on some early Pentiums. Possibly the advice was sensible once but was simply a little dated, mind he may have first done the research some time before the talk and it may have been on dated CPUs even then, I could see it being possible that he could have come to that conclusion. However pretty much all documentations say that the `mov` `mfence` path is faster on modern CPUs if not very old ones.

Comment: `mov`+`mfence` is slower in practice; GCC recently switched away from it for seq_cst stores, now using `xchg` like other compilers.  It already needs to get a copy of the cache line into Exclusive ownership state (except for full-line writes, committing a store requires an up-to-date copy of the line), so the extra read is not at all significant.  See also [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40409297) and note the Skylake microcode update that gave `mfence` an `lfence`-like barrier to OoO exec, unlike `xchg`.

Comment: @PeterCordes This may well be true now. It's been about a decade since I last investigated this (look at the answer age). I don't have time right now to update this answer but if you can write a more up to date one (saying more or less what you said in your comment) I am sure OP would appreciate it and I would happily upvote.

Comment: There are existing Q&As that cover it, probably we can close this as a duplicate.  I had another look for some, and found [What is the difference in logic and performance between LOCK XCHG and MOV+MFENCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19096112) which itself has some duplicate links.  My answer on [Which is a better write barrier on x86: lock+addl or xchgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52910647) at least mentions it.  Ah, finally found a good answer about the perf diff: [Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49107683)