# Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, lock-free, stdatomic

Why is [`std::atomic`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) [`store`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store):

```
std::atomic<int> my_atomic;
my_atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

doing an [`xchg`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html) when a store with sequential consistency is requested?

---

Shouldn't, technically, a normal store with a read/write memory barrier be enough? Equivalent to:

```
_ReadWriteBarrier(); // Or `asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` for gcc/clang
my_atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
```

I'm explicitly talking about x86 & x86_64. Where a store has an implicit acquire fence.

Comment: @DanielLangr Both `_ReadWriteBarrier()` and `asm volatile("" ::: "memory")` are compiler fences, and do not translate into any fence instructions.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's not about the fence, but rather about why the whole operation is implemented as an `xchg` as opposed to a simple `mov` (which is also atomic, assuming the target is correctly aligned).

Comment: _"Where a store has an implicit acquire fence."_ But you need **both release and acquire fence** for sequential consistency. Compiler barrier only prevents reordering at compiler level, not at CPU level.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**[`mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov)-store + [`mfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mfence) and [`xchg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg) are both valid ways to implement a sequential-consistency store on x86.**  The implicit `lock` prefix on an `xchg` with memory makes it a full memory barrier, like all atomic RMW  operations on x86.

(x86's memory-ordering rules essentially make that full-barrier effect the only option for any atomic RMW: it's both a load and a store at the same time, stuck together in the global order.  Atomicity requires that the load and store aren't separated by just queuing the store into the store buffer so it has to be drained, and load-load ordering of the load side requires that it not reorder.)

**Plain `mov` is not sufficient; it only has release semantics, not sequential-release**.  (Unlike AArch64's `stlr` instruction, which does do a sequential-release store that can't reorder with later `ldar` sequential-acquire loads.  This choice is obviously motivated by C++11 having seq_cst as the default memory ordering.  But AArch64's normal store is much weaker; relaxed not release.)

See [Jeff Preshing's article on acquire / release semantics](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/), and note that regular release stores (like `mov` or any non-locked x86 memory-destination instruction other than xchg) allows reordering with later operations, including acquire loads (like mov or any x86 memory-source operand).  e.g. If the release-store is releasing a lock, it's ok for later stuff to appear to happen inside the critical section.

---

**There are performance differences between `mfence` and `xchg` on different CPUs**, and maybe in the hot vs. cold cache and contended vs. uncontended cases.  And/or for throughput of many operations back to back in the same thread vs. for one on its own, and for allowing surrounding code to overlap execution with the atomic operation.

See https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies for actual benchmarks of `mfence` vs. `lock addl $0, -8(%rsp)` vs. `(%rsp)` as a full barrier (when you don't already have a store to do).

On Intel Skylake hardware, *`mfence` blocks out-of-order execution of independent ALU instructions, but `xchg` doesn't*.  ([See my test asm + results in the bottom of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379)).  Intel's manuals don't require it to be that strong; only `lfence` is documented to do that.  But as an implementation detail, it's very expensive for out-of-order execution of surrounding code on Skylake.

I haven't tested other CPUs, and **this may be a result of [a microcode fix for erratum SKL079](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fa.linux.kernel/hNOoIZc6I9E/WlyXcgwoCwAJ)**, *SKL079   MOVNTDQA From WC Memory May Pass* Earlier *MFENCE Instructions*.  The existence of the erratum basically proves that SKL used to be able to execute instructions after MFENCE.  I wouldn't be surprised if they fixed it by making MFENCE stronger in microcode, kind of a blunt instrument approach that significantly increases the impact on surrounding code.

I've only tested the single-threaded case where the cache line is hot in L1d cache.  (Not when it's cold in memory, or when it's in Modified state on another core.)  `xchg` has to load the previous value, creating a "false" dependency on the old value that was in memory.  But `mfence` forces the CPU to wait until previous stores commit to L1d, which also requires the cache line to arrive (and be in M state).  So they're probably about equal in that respect, but Intel's `mfence` forces everything to wait, not just loads.

**AMD's optimization manual recommends `xchg` for atomic seq-cst stores**.  I thought Intel recommended `mov` + `mfence`, which older gcc uses, but **Intel's compiler also uses `xchg`** here.

When I tested, I got better throughput on Skylake for `xchg` than for `mov`+`mfence` in a single-threaded loop on the same location repeatedly.  See [Agner Fog's microarch guide and instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/) for some details, but he doesn't spend much time on locked operations.

**See [gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC output on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYRYkAtgW7zcXAAwBBcxeFFMIEHvSHj2pUS251%2BgJ4B9JxctAUtrADd0Akx1ADN0dAh3dQAPAEpNAHYQi3Vc739Ao015ABF1ABZg3IB6apTrLgyShssIqNjsZWwIdMbsvPVbe0cDIz8iJFJsFkw/GM6pCCGHfWx9Mn8yHFI/YWwARz9UW1TghqaZVOZZAFYZcjZZM3v0WW1BQUHxSWxNHnl6PciE9LlcANYgeTyAB0ULh8IRADZrjJyvd9CAbmYHiDyK8ZPdhCBscCZM8rnBYCgMPoAA4EJjYChUCA0%2BmM0ggYAADkYMQZRCZRIgACNcSKlCxSD5ZIDyDTVmwiAB5NhMGVk%2B44fTsYCM3GEKaoIgEMLYIma8jYZLYVBiQWy%2B7ubBMXFEUgEDEyQFXVgcNAffjMAgiomQK7oWkm9BsC0AWgA6iwmEx1HHlfI0zrJEgtCVhGCfKwwb84/p5Dws2x0HHhHseITvlIGL7bvdHpb8cluYi44jyupgKhUOpudD6OoIPhiGQ/gDyOptM52Uy5zd0u9%2BIIgSDUlckNNttRW6j0ZjsR3nnjZITieRSeTwZCYQjX3Dka6ZPJ27j8TvNRSiCUsgaDLgyTKUNQbLgZyPJ8gKQrUGKloSmwUoanKCqdCqaoale2q6vqlqGraJpmhaV7Wra9rSN6TpKi6boel6PrMLqAZbkGTAhmGPR4lGBAxvGSYpmmGZZlKqC5qUBZFiwJaNhIzb0Cedw4p2sjdr2/aDsOo7jpO04kKQc6MIuYEcqZG6Bnw/6PuQEJQrCb6vh%2BshouQGLlIi0I3Ny8gZOUGQAJw8BkZgAjcjCXi8N4iHeD6XOQwEQNSFkQSy0EcmgfrAIiZjYvyTCCqQwrIVeqHoY68rOIqOHqgaayEbR%2BEEEaZHmriVF2g6dGUAxn5Xu6nqOr67HcJxQjcaG8ARgJQmyLWdh5sAbBiDZ9ADomyapummZLZg015tNE0CPwik/C2KJqTF14yFpfYDiourqD5ZjQmYhmEMZpkLkudIwXOPDWZNdmguQB4zEyx4oh5GI3DC5T0IiPA3DwZgZDwwWItyNzqVef7xSSu5Pk5LmuSi3747FBL3ruyVAUBaUAxykGsulnJGKg9DcuQRUlWV4qStK1VYUqqoNcRTUcERrXtaanWWt1NHVc6g1Asxo1sf6p2CMGM3hvx0axotIm7RmF3KapP4afdPaPeoXPqDzH0fV9M4mQoZn/Sunv/PIINnbZdMAaTL7k/CsNnuU5S%2BRkGT0Jt5RhT2GPU3dt7EwBDPwKloEsxlUEczlfhsNgADufj9nzCGlUhQtoSLfVi/VeFatLeotVqbWkQrFH3MrvVymrTEjXRY06zZ%2Bu8XNxvxsqySW9IKnXTbBOafbOkALIAMoAGraOoAAKUzqOjPPuz9Xt/Rzc7lIH24h/ZkNHnxn5w5iNzQsnPDcrjNyY3oPIYK8h06EyJFneyjlw4RyhJTNeNMwZ7hRA2MBcVErILNKVQSjxyhAA%3D%3D) for a C++11 seq-cst `my_atomic = 4;`**  gcc uses `mov` + `mfence` when SSE2 is available.  (use `-m32 -mno-sse2` to get gcc to use `xchg` too).  The other 3 compilers all prefer `xchg` with default tuning, or for `znver1` (Ryzen) or `skylake`.

The Linux kernel uses `xchg` for  `__smp_store_mb()`.

Update: recent GCC (like GCC10) changed to using `xchg` for seq-cst stores like other compilers do, even when SSE2 for `mfence` is available.

---

**Another interesting question is how to compile `atomic_thread_fence(mo_seq_cst);`**.  The obvious option is `mfence`, but `lock or dword [rsp], 0` is another valid option (and used by `gcc -m32` when MFENCE isn't available).  The bottom of the stack is usually already hot in cache in M state.  The downside is introducing latency if a local was stored there.  (If it's just a return address, return-address prediction is usually very good so delaying `ret`'s ability to read it is not much of a problem.)  So `lock or dword [rsp-4], 0` could be worth considering in some cases.  ([gcc did consider it](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/729578/), but reverted it because it makes valgrind unhappy.  This was before it was known that it might be better than `mfence` even when `mfence` was available.)

All compilers currently use `mfence` for a stand-alone barrier when it's available.  Those are rare in C++11 code, but more research is needed on what's actually most efficient for real multi-threaded code that has real work going on inside the threads that are communicating locklessly.

**But multiple source recommend using `lock add` to the stack as a barrier instead of `mfence`**, so the Linux kernel recently switched to using it for the `smp_mb()` implementation on x86, even when SSE2 is available.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fa.linux.kernel/hNOoIZc6I9E/pVO3hB5ABAAJ for some discussion, including a mention of some errata for HSW/BDW about `movntdqa` loads from WC memory passing earlier `lock`ed instructions.  (Opposite of Skylake, where it was `mfence` instead of `lock`ed instructions that were a problem.  But unlike SKL, there's no fix in microcode.  This may be why Linux still uses `mfence` for its `mb()` for drivers, in case anything ever uses NT loads to copy back from video RAM or something but can't let the reads happen until after an earlier store is visible.)

- [In Linux 4.14](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h), `smp_mb()` uses `mb()`.  That uses mfence is used if available, otherwise `lock addl $0, 0(%esp)`.

  `__smp_store_mb` (store + memory barrier) uses `xchg` (and that doesn't change in later kernels).
- [In Linux 4.15](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h), `smb_mb()` uses `lock; addl $0,-4(%esp)` or `%rsp`, instead of using `mb()`.  (The kernel doesn't use a red-zone even in 64-bit, so the `-4` may help avoid extra latency for local vars).

  `mb()` is used by drivers to order access to MMIO regions, but `smp_mb()` turns into a no-op when compiled for a uniprocessor system.  Changing `mb()` is riskier because it's harder to test (affects drivers), and CPUs have errata related to lock vs. mfence.  But anyway, `mb()` uses mfence if available, else `lock addl $0, -4(%esp)`.  The only change is the `-4`.
- [In Linux 4.16](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h), no change except removing the `#if defined(CONFIG_X86_PPRO_FENCE)` which defined stuff for a more weakly-ordered memory model than the x86-TSO model that modern hardware implements.

---

> x86 & x86_64. Where a store has an implicit acquire fence

You mean *release*, I hope.  `my_atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_acquire);` won't compile, because write-only atomic operations can't be acquire operations.  See also [Jeff Preshing's article on acquire/release semantics](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

> Or `asm volatile("" ::: "memory");`

No, that's a compiler barrier only; it prevents all [compile-time reordering](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) across it, but doesn't prevent [runtime StoreLoad reordering](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/), i.e. the store being buffered until later, and not appearing in the global order until after a later load.  (StoreLoad is the only kind of runtime reordering x86 allows.)

Anyway, another way to express what you want here is:

```
my_atomic.store(1, std::memory_order_release);        // mov
// with no operations in between, there's nothing for the release-store to be delayed past
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);  // mfence
```

Using a release fence would not be strong enough (it and the release-store could both be delayed past a later load, which is the same thing as saying that release fences don't keep later loads from happening early).  A release-acquire fence would do the trick, though, keeping later loads from happening early and not itself being able to reorder with the release store.

Related: [Jeff Preshing's article on fences being different from release operations](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/).

But note that seq-cst is special according to C++11 rules: only seq-cst operations are guaranteed to have a single global / total order which all threads agree on seeing.  So emulating them with weaker order + fences might not be exactly equivalent in general on the C++ abstract machine, even if it is on x86.  (On x86, all store have a single total order which all cores agree on.  See also [Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609934/globally-invisible-load-instructions): Loads can take their data from the store buffer, so we can't really say that there's a total order for loads + stores.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, that clears everything up! I read the great articles from Jeff Preshing, which left me at this question. I got the implicit ordering confused.