# Acquire-release on x86

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86, x86-64

In the Intel Manual Vol.3 there is an example of loads reordering with early stores.

Initially `x = y = 0`

**Core 1**:

```
mov [x], 1
mov r2, [y]
```

**Core 2**:

```
mov [y], 1
mov r1, [x]
```

So `r1 = r2 = 0` is possible. The question is if requiring acquire-release prohibits such scenario? On x86 store is a release store so I think no. Example:

**Core 1**:

```
release(mov [x], 1)
mov r2, [y]
```

**Core 2**:

```
mov [y], 1
acquire(mov r1, [x])
```

In this case if `acquire(mov r1, [x])` loads observe 0 then it's only possible to conclude that `release(mov [x], 1)` is not **synchronized-with** `acquire(mov r1, [x])` in terms of the **C11 Standard memory model specification** standpoint, and it does not provide any guarantees which could prohibit reordering `mov [y], 1` and `acquire(mov r1, [x])` on the **Core 2**

Comment: Related: [Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49107683) re: what you do if you want stronger ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, acquire/release semantics cannot prevent StoreLoad reordering, i.e. taking a store followed by a load and interchanging their order.  And such reordering is allowed for ordinary load and store instructions on x86.

If you want to avoid such reordering in C11, you need to use `memory_order_seq_cst` on both the store and the load.  In x86 assembly, you need a barrier in between the two instructions.  `mfence` serves this purpose, but so does any `lock`ed read-modify-write instruction, including `xchg` which does so even without the `lock` prefix.  So if you look at the generated assembly for `memory_order_seq_cst` operations, you'll see some such barrier in between.  (For certain [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence), something like `lock add [rsp], 0`, or `xchg` between some register and memory whose contents are unimportant, can actually be more performant than `mfence`, so some compilers will do that even though it looks weird.)

Comment: x86 compilers typically implement `x.store(value, seq_cst)` as `mov eax, value` / `xchg [x], eax` or similar, using xchg to actually do the store, as well as being a full barrier.  Not xchg with *unimportant* memory contents.  But yes, https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act demos this StoreLoad reordering litmus test on x86, showing that x86's program-order + a store buffer with store forwarding does allow StoreLoad reordering.