# Sequentially consistent fence

Tags: c++, x86, kernel, atomic, memory-barriers

I have kernel code and userspace code that synchronize on atomic variables. The kernel and userspace code may be running on the same logical core or different logical cores. Let's assume the architecture is x86_64.

Here is an initial implementation to get our feet wet:

```
Kernel (C)                        Userspace (C++)
---------------------------       -----------------------------------
Store A (smp_store_release)       Store B (std::memory_order_release)
Load B (smp_load_acquire)         Load A (std::memory_order_acquire)
```

I require that from the perspective of each thread, its own load happens after its own store. So for example, from userspace's perspective, the load to A must happen after the store to B.

Furthermore, I similarly require that for a given thread, it observes the *other* thread do the load after the store. So for example, from the kernel's perspective, it must observe that userspace stores to B before loading A.

Clearly, the code above is insufficient to meet these two requirements, so for the sake of this question, I rewrite it as so:

```
Kernel (C)                        Userspace (C++)
---------------------------       -----------------------------------
Store A (smp_store_release)       Store B (std::memory_order_release)
cpuid                             std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
Load B (smp_load_acquire)         Load A (std::memory_order_acquire)
```

According to the Intel manual, `cpuid` is a serializing operation.

Here are my questions:

1. If I issue `cpuid` with the asm compiler-level `memory` barrier, does this have the same behavior as a sequentially consistent fence?
2. Now let's say I issue `cpuid` **without** the asm compiler-level `memory` barrier. Furthermore, let's say that the store to A is standard kernel code while the load to B is done by a BPF program. Does `cpuid` have the same behavior as a sequentially consistent fence in this case? My impression is that it does, because (1) `cpuid` provides hardware serialization and (2) compiler reordering is impossible since the kernel is compiled separately from the BPF program.
3. The C++ standard requires that synchronization occur between threads on the same address. It seems that issuing an `mfence` (or another type of fence) is sufficient to achieve hardware serialization, and `mfence` does not have a memory address as an argument. Thus, does the standard impose this requirement solely to prevent compiler reordering?

Answer (score 2):

Reordering, and serialization (ordering), are things that only apply within the current thread, for the global visibility of its accesses to coherent shared cache.  See https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/. Barriers alone don't sync with another thread.  Sufficient barriers can ensure that the order of operations is some interleaving of program order (e.g. if all atomic ops use `seq_cst`), not that some load in another thread actually will see some store in this thread; it might have already happened and you can't rewind time.

---

On x86, to do a store that can't reorder with any later loads (or anything else in any direction), use `xchg`.  It has an implicit `lock` prefix that makes it a full barrier.

To get that from modern compilers, use `B.store(value, std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, where `seq_cst` is the default anyway.  (Older GCC used to compile that to a `mov`-store + `mfence`, which is equivalent: [Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107683/why-does-a-stdatomic-store-with-sequential-consistency-use-xchg))

To document in your source that you don't want the later load to reorder with that store, make it `seq_cst` as well, like `A.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.

ISO C++ guarantees that `seq_cst` operations are part of a global total order that's consistent with source order, so `seq_cst` operations don't allow StoreLoad reordering with each other.

That's actually important on some other ISAs, notably AArch64, where a `seq_cst` store can reorder with later loads that aren't `seq_cst`.  Only `stlr` / `ldar` have the special interaction that prevents StoreLoad reordering.  An `acquire` load using `ldapr` doesn't have to wait for older `stlr` stores to commit to L1d cache.

x86 doesn't (yet?) have hardware support for doing anything  weaker than a full barrier after or as part of the store but still strong enough for `seq_cst`, unlike AArch64.  But there's no reason to write the source with weaker operations like `acquire` and rely on asm details to give you the StoreLoad ordering you need: You can still just use `B.store(val)` ; `A.load()` with both using the default `seq_cst` (or make it explicit).  That will compile safely and cheaply on x86 and everywhere else.  (x86 `seq_cst` loads are just plain loads because the cost of avoiding StoreLoad reordering is already done in every `seq_cst` store.  [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html))

A `seq_cst` store is also a release operation, and a `seq_cst` load is also an acquire operation, in case you're worried about using `seq_cst` instead of `std::memory_order_release`.

If your kernel code doesn't support a seq_cst store operation, put a seq_cst fence / full barrier between its store and load.  The same thing would work with `std::atomic` in C++, it's just more efficient to let the compiler include the barrier as part of the SC store, instead of needing a separate `mfence` or dummy `lock add byte [rsp], 0` or something to implement a separate `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.

---

I have no idea why you think `cpuid` would be a good idea here since you only have data stores/loads, not cross-modifying code or anything tricky.  Perhaps you're thinking that "serialize" implies affecting other cores? It doesn't.  But to answer your questions:

1. Yes, `cpuid` is at least as strong a barrier as `mfence`, stronger in some ways (re: code fetch for cross-modifying code IIRC).  When you say "asm compiler-level `memory` barrier", you're talking about `asm("cpuid" ::: "memory", "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx")`, a GNU C asm statement with a `"memory"` *clobber*?  (And register clobbers on the regs CPUID writes, unlike [the new `serialize` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/serialize) in Sapphire Rapids IIRC, which probably also avoids being a vmexit the way CPUID always is in VMs.)
2. Yes, if there's no chance for compile-time reordering between the ops you care about, `asm("mfence" ::: );` is sufficient, but not a good idea.
3. Serializing (ordering) the global visibility of memory operations on the current core or thread doesn't sync with another thread on its own.  To sync-with another thread and create a happens-before relationship, you need a load in this thread to see a store done by the other thread.  Specifically an acquire (or stronger) load seeing a release (or stronger) store, or equivalent barriers.

   See https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ re: writing a buffer then `data_ready.store(true, std::memory_order_release)`, so a reader that reads `data_ready` as `true` can safely read the buffer and see the earlier non-atomic stores done by the writer.

   Just running a barrier instruction to order your own loads+stores after a `data_ready.load()` doesn't help anything if the writer is still in the middle of writing the buffer and hasn't stored to `data_ready` yet.

   Memory fences aka barriers aren't like a [`pthread_barrier()` synchronization operation](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/pthread_barrier.3.html) where every thread reaching it waits until all threads have reached it.  Totally different concept.