# Generic Volatile.Read to Thread.VolatileRead conversion

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, volatile, lock-free

I need to get this code from .NET 4.5+ working on .NET 4.0. The generic `Volatile.Read` isn't available in that version. I'm trying to use the `Thread.VolatileRead` to get this working. I need to know if this outright a bad idea and if not, what I should test for?

See what I replaced in the commented line.

```
internal static TValue EnsureSingletonInitialized<TValue, TArg>(ref TValue value,
    TArg arg, Func<TArg, TValue> initialize)
    where TValue : class
{
    //TValue currentValue = Volatile.Read(ref value);

    object o = value;
    TValue currentValue = (TValue)Thread.VolatileRead(ref o);

    if (null != currentValue)
        return currentValue;

    TValue candidateValue = initialize(arg);

    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, candidateValue, null) ?? candidateValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest implementations of the missing `Read<T>`/`Write<T>` methods are probably these:

```
public static class VolatileEx
{
    public static T Read<T>(ref T location) where T : class
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, null, null);
    }

    public static void Write<T>(ref T location, T value) where T : class
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref location, value);
    }
}
```

Using the [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) ensures that the `Read`/`Write` are atomic, and also that the preceding/following instructions will not be reordered. The `Interlocked` APIs impose full memory barriers, so they are more expensive than the [`Volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile) APIs that impose half fences. But since you downgraded to an older .NET platform, losing some performance is to be expected.

Source code:

- [`Thread.VolatileRead`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,1684) (.NET Framework)
- [`Volatile.Read`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0656c910d9384a2628549f034f0d111caa2e1da3/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Volatile.cs#L221) (.NET 7)

Comment: `Thread.VolatileRead` should work; as a non-inline function it can't optimize away the load.  It includes a full `MemoryBarrier();` so it's much less efficient than `Volatile.Read`, but doesn't dirty the cache line it's reading (which `lock cmpxchg` does).  I assume C# guarantees that narrow-enough accesses are automatically atomic, since obviously the intent of `Thread.VolatileRead` is inter-thread communication, but the source just uses plain assignment on ordinary objects.

Comment: Using `xchg` for a store is equivalent (and more efficient) than `Thread.VolatileWrite` doing an assignment and then a separate `MemoryBarrier();`, at least on x86 ([Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49107683)).  Perhaps less efficient on other ISAs if they have a more efficient `MemoryBarrier()`.