# Why are clang and GCC not using xchg to implement std::swap?

Tags: c++, compilation, x86, swap

I have the following code:

```cpp
char swap(char reg, char* mem) {
    std::swap(reg, *mem);
    return reg;
}
```

I expected this to compile down to:

```cpp
swap(char, char*):
    xchg    dil, byte ptr [rsi]
    mov     al, dil
    ret
```

But what it actually compiles to is (at `-O3 -march=haswell -std=c++20`):

```cpp
swap(char, char*):
    mov     al, byte ptr [rsi]
    mov     byte ptr [rsi], dil
    ret
```

See [here for a live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ehnKbb).

From the documentation of `xchg`, the first form should be perfectly possible:

> #### XCHG - Exchange Register/Memory with Register
>
> Exchanges the contents of the destination (first) and source (second) operands. The operands can be two general-purpose registers or a register and a memory location.

So is there any particular reason why it's not possible for the compiler to use `xchg` here? I have tried other examples too, such as swapping pointers, swapping three operands, swapping types other than `char` but I never get an `xchg` in the compile output. How come?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL:DR: because compilers optimize for speed, not for names that sound similar.  There are lots of other terrible ways they also could have implemented it, but chose not to.

**xchg with mem has an implicit `lock` prefix (on 386 and later) so it's horribly slow**.  You always want to avoid it unless you *need* an atomic exchange, or are optimizing completely for code-size without caring *at all* for performance, in cases where you do want the result in the same register as the original value.  Sometimes seen in naive (performance oblivious) or [code-golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list/149038#149038) hand-written Bubble Sort as part of swapping 2 memory locations.

Possibly `clang -Oz` could go that crazy, IDK, but hopefully wouldn't in this case because your xchg way is larger code size, needing a REX prefix on both instructions to access DIL, vs. the 2-mov way being a 2-byte and a 3-byte instruction.  `clang -Oz` does do stuff like `push 1` / `pop rax` instead of `mov eax, 1` to save 2 bytes of code size.

GCC `-Os` won't use `xchg` for swaps that don't need to be atomic because `-Os` still cares *some* about speed.

---

Also, IDK why would you think xchg + dependent mov would be faster or a better choice than two independent `mov` instructions that can run in parallel.  (The store buffer makes sure that the store is correctly ordered after the load, regardless of which uop finds its execution port free first).

See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Seriously, I just don't see any plausible reason why you'd think a compiler might want to use `xchg`, especially given that the calling convention doesn't pass an arg in RAX so you still need 2 instructions.  Even for registers, `xchg reg,reg` on Intel CPUs is 3 uops, and they're microcode uops that can't benefit from mov-elimination.  (Some AMD CPUs have 2-uop `xchg reg,reg`.  [Why is XCHG reg, reg a 3 micro-op instruction on modern Intel architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures))

---

I also guess you're looking at clang output; [GCC will avoid partial register shenanigans (like false dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) by using a `movzx eax, byte ptr [rsi]` load even though the return value is only the low byte.  Zero-extending loads are cheaper than merging into the old value of RAX.  So that's another downside to `xchg`.

Comment: Related: re history of `xchg` having an implicit lock prefix on 386 and newer: *[How to exchange top of stack with register without implicit lock on latest 64 bit Intel CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55880117)*

Answer (score 4):

> So is there any particular reason why it's not possible for the compiler to use xchg here?

Because `mov` is faster than `xchg` and compilers optimize for speed.

See:

- [Why is XCHG reg, reg a 3 micro-op instruction on modern Intel architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures)
- [Why does GCC use mov/mfence instead of xchg to implement C11's atomic_store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909997/why-does-gcc-use-mov-mfence-instead-of-xchg-to-implement-c11s-atomic-store)
- [Use xchg for -Os](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2019-11/msg01839.html)
- [Bug 47949 - Missed optimization for -Os using xchg instead of mov](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47949)